# What is a spanid and what are the consequences of using it in LogEntrys?

Tags: google-cloud-logging

I've noticed there's an optional span_id/spanid in a LogEntry.
It is an [unsigned 64-bit integer, attached to the concept "trace span"](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/viewing-details#log_entries), which is [defined in the top level of the LogEntry](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-filters#comparisons) and [it is an id within a trace](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#logseverity).

I've tried sending custom logs to stackdriver with and without a spanid. So far, I have been unable to produce any results. All entries in the log look the exact same except they have an additional metadata (spanid).

What are the consequences of using a spanid? What can I do with a spanid which I wouldn't be able to without?

Answer (score 2):

The Span ID is only useful if you are using the Stackdriver trace API as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/reference/#spans). If you are not using the Stackdriver Trace API, then having the Span ID will not change anything.